# Не отображается картинка в через путь src в img

Tags: javascript, html, css

как бы путь не задавал, картинка не отображается, использую гугл хром, запускаю сервер через gulp, папка с проектом находиться на рабочем столе, путь такой:

CatEnergy/build/images/icon-cat-slim.svg - как правильно задать путь?

у меня так:

```
<img class="offer__img" src="./images/icon-cat-slim.svg" alt="иконка" width="36" height="50">
```

Comment: По какому пути открыта страница?

Comment: @Igor ~/Desktop/CatEnergy/gulpfile.js по gulp так

Answer (score 0):

Со сборщиком часто бывают нюансы с путями, я делал через webpack, там пути он меняется на новые скомпилированные, открой код на запущенном сайте через просмотр кода элемента, и увидь какой путь, и там же попробуй подставить

```
<img class="offer__img" src="/images/icon-cat.svg" alt="иконка" width="36" height="50">
```

а ещё я заметил, что название отличается icon-cat.svg и icon-cat-slim.svg

Comment: я исправил путь(просто забыл дописать slim), но просто до этого у меня путь был к папке которая не обробатывалась gulp, а теперь хотел изменить и ничего не отображается(

Comment: сейчас работает?

Comment: нет, питался уже все пути использовать(

Comment: Попробуй в браузере нажать на ссылку открыть в новой вкладке и там путь поменяй на необходимый (я так для отладки делал) либо если несложно, я могу сделать(но нужны все файлы) github | файлообменник

Comment: у меня стоит reload в gulp, страница перезагружается когда я меняю в html файле пути, я уже много вариантов испробовал но пока безуспешно